# Sample size calculation for the comparison of the means of three groups

Tags: sample-size, continuous-data

I have to calculate the sample size for my project. The study is a comparison between three different treatments at three different time points. The outcome variable takes continuous values. We express it in mean and SD. So what is the sample size formula for this study?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simulation that will generate the necessary sample that would generate significant value (p< 0.05). I don't know what programing language you use, but I will put my matlab code which I use for this purpose. Note that the code only deals with 2 groups, not three. So you have to adjust the code a little bit. Nevertheless, the idea should be the same.

```
% This program tries to find out what is the minimum number N (subjects) to
% assure a significant correlation between two predefined distributions.


subjects = 100;
simulations = 1000;  % How many simulations we need to run ?
data = []; % our final output

% for the plot you'll see below, you'll need those numbers. 

mean1=70; % say this is the mean length of men
mean2=65; % say this is the mean length of women
sd1=10;
sd2=10;

for s=1:subjects
    result = [];
    for i=1:simulations,

        % random sample of length s (subjects), multiply by std and add the mean

        b = rand(s,1)*sd1+mean1;
        g = rand(s,1)*sd2+mean2;

        % do the t-test

        [h,p] = ttest2(b,g);

        if h == 1,
            % if p value is significant then add 1 to our results list
            result = [result 1];
        else
            result = [result 0];
        end
    end

    % then, take the mean of significant results and add it to our final
    % list with the number of simulated subjects
    data = [data; s mean(result)];
end

% plot the results

plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))
```

The resulting plot should look like this. The plot shows the mean significant comparisons of 1000 simulations for each number of sample (x-axis). We see that the the values becomes significant from x=15 onwards.

[image: The mean significant comparisons of 1000 simulations for each number of sample (x-axis). We see that the the values becomes significant from x=15 onwards]